# The Jquery Focus is not working for input

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The Jquery Focus is not working for a single input button click is working only problem is with the input field as shown in the below code:

> Not working only for single input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $("#val").change(function(){
        $("input").focus();
        $("p").html("focus event triggered");
    });  
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("input").focus();
        $("p").html("focus event triggered");
    });  
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("input").blur();
        $("p").html("blur event triggered");
    }); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input id="val" type="text">
<br><br>

<button id="btn1">Trigger focus event</button>
<button id="btn2">Trigger blur event</button>

<p style="color:red"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have added the jsfiddle link below :https://jsfiddle.net/Manishankarg/0ony2ovb/

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? for me looks to be working totally fine

Comment: It's working. You just check it. I click on button it Focused in input element

Comment: i think what you're looking for is `on('input', () => {})` event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is to retain focus even on clicking tab then you will have to use keydown() instead of change().

Actually  your code is working fine. Only that the change() is not triggered the second time you press tab without changing the input.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#val").keydown(function(e){
            if(e.which == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("p").html("focus event triggered");        
        }
    });  
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#val").focus();
        $("p").html("focus event triggered");
    });  
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("input").blur();
        $("p").html("blur event triggered");
    }); 
});
```

I have added the jsfiddle link below : [Keydown Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Arun_Chidanandan/ddpmn8g3/)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you're question correct you just have to change the change function to the blur function in your javascript function.
This will trigger the focus on the input element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $("#val").on('blur', function(e){
        $("input").focus();
        $("p").html("focus event triggered");
    });  
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("input").focus();
        $("p").html("focus event triggered");
    });  
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("input").blur();
        $("p").html("blur event triggered");
    }); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input id="val" type="text">
<br><br>

<button id="btn1">Trigger focus event</button>
<button id="btn2">Trigger blur event</button>

<p style="color:red"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, my question is when ever I edit textbox and press tab, the focus() in on change text box  is not working

Comment: I changed the change function to blur, is this what you mean?

Comment: No, What i want is even after editing the textbox, if the user press tab, still the focus should be in the textbox only.

Comment: When I add a second input box and change the first $("input").focus(); to  $(this).focus(); I can't tab because the text field is automatically focused again. So that sounds exactly like what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#val").on('input', function(){
        $("input").focus();
        $("p").html("focus event triggered");
    });  
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("input").focus();
        $("p").html("focus event triggered");
    });  
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("input").blur();
        $("p").html("blur event triggered");
    }); 
});
```

i think what you're trying to do is to trigger change event when input value changed